# Excel macro to read text file word by word and write every word to a new cell in the same column

Tags: excel, vba, text

I have a huge txt file with email ids delimited by `,`  (space), or `;`, or a combination of these.

I would like to separate these email ids and write them into new cells in just one column, row after row in the excel file.

Excel's delimited import is unable to show all ids as there are only 256 columns. And the number of words I have run into thousands. And is best suited to be inserted row by row into a new cell of the same column.

input text file looks like:

```
abc@abc.com; xyx@xyc.com, ext@124.de, abcd@cycd.com
```

required output to excel file:

```
abc@abc.com
xyx@xyc.com
ext@124.de 
abcd@cycd.com
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? A good start could be [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) or [the internet](http://www.google.com).

Comment: Things to look up: _file i/o_, _split_ and _entering text in cells_... :)

Comment: @OlleSjögren -- I've tried all over stackoverflow and the internet too, tried a few codes I found on the net, I have very limited programming knowledge, I'm a photographer by profession and this is a real life problem i have... I have done some very basic VB programming about 15 years ago and was trying to see if that would help.. I'm sure this is possible, just that I'm not equipped with the programming talent..

Comment: You could also try a good text editor and use search and replace to get rid of the delimiters and place every record on its own line. May be quicker for a non-programmer? Lots of good free editors around.

Answer (score 1):

Reference: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/A_1480-How-to-Split-a-String-with-Multiple-Delimiters-in-VBA.html

Your question contains a few part

1.Read txt file into a string (Excel has string limit) I have tried receiving an Error message "Out of String Space" , so I hope your "Huge" file isn't > 1G or something

2.Split them by mutli-delimiters

3.Output email per row

```
Sub Testing()
    Dim fname As String
    Dim sVal As String
    Dim count As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Replace Sheet1 with the output sheet name you want
    fname = "H:\My Documents\a.txt"   'Replace the path with your txt file path
    sVal = OpenTextFileToString2(fname)
    Dim tmp As Variant
    tmp = SplitMultiDelims(sVal, ",; ", True)   ' Place the 2nd argument with the list of delimiter you need to use
    count = 0
    For i = LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1)

         count = count + 1
         ws.Cells(count, 1) = tmp(i)  'output on the first column

    Next i
End Sub    


Function OpenTextFileToString2(ByVal strFile As String) As String
' RB Smissaert - Author
Dim hFile As Long
hFile = FreeFile
Open strFile For Input As #hFile
OpenTextFileToString2 = Input$(LOF(hFile), hFile)
Close #hFile
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' SplitMultiDelims by alainbryden
' This function splits Text into an array of substrings, each substring
' delimited by any character in DelimChars. Only a single character
' may be a delimiter between two substrings, but DelimChars may
' contain any number of delimiter characters. It returns a single element
' array containing all of text if DelimChars is empty, or a 1 or greater
' element array if the Text is successfully split into substrings.
' If IgnoreConsecutiveDelimiters is true, empty array elements will not occur.
' If Limit greater than 0, the function will only split Text into 'Limit'
' array elements or less. The last element will contain the rest of Text.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function SplitMultiDelims(ByRef Text As String, ByRef DelimChars As String, _
        Optional ByVal IgnoreConsecutiveDelimiters As Boolean = False, _
        Optional ByVal Limit As Long = -1) As String()
    Dim ElemStart As Long, N As Long, M As Long, Elements As Long
    Dim lDelims As Long, lText As Long
    Dim Arr() As String

    lText = Len(Text)
    lDelims = Len(DelimChars)
    If lDelims = 0 Or lText = 0 Or Limit = 1 Then
        ReDim Arr(0 To 0)
        Arr(0) = Text
        SplitMultiDelims = Arr
        Exit Function
    End If
    ReDim Arr(0 To IIf(Limit = -1, lText - 1, Limit))

    Elements = 0: ElemStart = 1
    For N = 1 To lText
        If InStr(DelimChars, Mid(Text, N, 1)) Then
            Arr(Elements) = Mid(Text, ElemStart, N - ElemStart)
            If IgnoreConsecutiveDelimiters Then
                If Len(Arr(Elements)) > 0 Then Elements = Elements + 1
            Else
                Elements = Elements + 1
            End If
            ElemStart = N + 1
            If Elements + 1 = Limit Then Exit For
        End If
    Next N
    'Get the last token terminated by the end of the string into the array
    If ElemStart <= lText Then Arr(Elements) = Mid(Text, ElemStart)
    'Since the end of string counts as the terminating delimiter, if the last character
    'was also a delimiter, we treat the two as consecutive, and so ignore the last elemnent
    If IgnoreConsecutiveDelimiters Then If Len(Arr(Elements)) = 0 Then Elements = Elements - 1

    ReDim Preserve Arr(0 To Elements) 'Chop off unused array elements
    SplitMultiDelims = Arr
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. It works like a dream :) Appreciate your time and the quick reply. cheers

Comment: yes I'm trying to dissect the code now and reverse engineer the logic. Appreciate it, cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
Sub importText()

Const theFile As String = "Your File Path"
Dim rng

Open theFile For Input As #1
    rng = Application.Transpose(Filter(Split(Replace(Replace(Input(LOF(1), 1), " ", ""), ",", ";"), ";"), "@"))
Close

Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(rng)).Value = rng

End Sub
```

**EDIT**
As per the suggestion, I've update the above to deal with consecutive mixed delimiters (,;) so the above will allow for something like:

```
abc@abc.com; xyx@xyc.com, ext@124.de, abcd@cycd.com;,;,; abc@abc.com;; xyx@xyc.com,,; ext@124.de, abcd@cycd.com
```

Comment: clear one, I simply stick to the question "or a combination of these."

Comment: Good point ;) updated to deal with consecutive, mixed delimiters (as long as they are ,; or a combination thereof